# Order by total points per user_id descending

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

```
select 
((select 
        COALESCE(sum(b.points_received), 0) as badge_total_points
    from
        user_badges ub
            join
        badges b ON ub.badge_id = b.badge_id
    where
        ub.user_id = '$user_id') + (select 
        COALESCE(sum(aps.given_points), 0) as total_action_points
    from
        user_action_points uap
            join
        action_point_system aps ON uap.point_id = aps.point_id
    where
        uap.user_id = '$user_id')) as total_contribution_points
```

how do I retrieve a list getting the total points grouped by a user_id with this SQL statement? Anybody have suggestions?

EDIT:

```
select 
ub.user_id,
COALESCE(sum(b.isGold), 0) as gold_count,
COALESCE(sum(b.isSilver), 0) as silver_count,
COALESCE(sum(b.isBronze), 0) as bronze_count
from
user_badges ub
    join
badges b ON ub.badge_id = b.badge_id
group by ub.user_id
```

how can I add this query to the result of the first question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are ways to do what you want, you can build on your existing query using correlated subqueries:

```
select u.*,
       ((select COALESCE(sum(b.points_received), 0) as badge_total_points
         from user_badges ub join
              badges b
              ON ub.badge_id = b.badge_id
         where ub.user_id = u.user_id
        ) +
        (select COALESCE(sum(aps.given_points), 0) as total_action_points
         from user_action_points uap join
              action_point_system aps
              ON uap.point_id = aps.point_id
         where uap.user_id = u.user_id
        )
       ) as total_contribution_points
from users u
order by total_contribution_points desc;
```

Comment: nice. thanks for answering quickly man... you said there are other ways to do this, what might some of them be? or what would be the best way to do the query?

Comment: hello can you also answer my follow up question